# Automate email alert notifications

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, web

I am able to code out interval or daily automate email alert sending but i cant seems to success in coding it that compared by 3 months.

my scenario is that this automate email system will have to retrieve and check my database table end dates of this contract, if the today date is just nice 3 months before the end date i need this system to auto generate an email to this contract client to remind them to contact us.

Any suggestion how can i code it? Your help is much appreciated !

**Edited**

@v2v2 Thanks for suggesting to use window service. Currently I am facing another problem is that I don't know how to change the interval to check for advance 3 months like what I described in my scenario above. 
Thanks in advance,Your help is much appreciated !

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key ="Mode" value ="DAILY"/>
    <!-- <add key ="Mode" value ="Interval"/>-->
    <add key ="IntervalMinutes" value ="1"/>
    <add key ="ScheduledTime" value ="19:01:00"/>
  </appSettings>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you write a code and use Window task schedular/ow window service/or program it itself in code.

Just for eg:

using System;
using Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler;

```
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      // Get the service on the local machine
      using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
      {
         // Create a new task definition and assign properties
         TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
         td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Does something";

         // Create a trigger that will fire the task at this time every other day
         td.Triggers.Add(new DailyTrigger { DaysInterval = 2 });

         // Create an action that will launch Notepad whenever the trigger fires
         td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction("notepad.exe", "c:\\test.log", null));

         // Register the task in the root folder
         ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(@"Test", td);

         // Remove the task we just created
         ts.RootFolder.DeleteTask("Test");
      }
   }
}
```

Or use Window service.Use google and try ,you can find enough Method.Please try yourself and then paste code if you need some help on that.

Comment: Any idea on how to change the app config above?@v2v2